# Groovy interpolation in shell step (Jenkins Pipelines)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, sh, string-interpolation

Just for my curiosity I have a question related to the groovy behavior in the shell step.

I have defined an environment variable REGISTRY_AT in Jenkins and a build parameter VERSION. I know that for Groovy to do substitution on variables they need to be enclosed in double quotes and from experience the following example works.

**Example:**

```html
dir('metrics/metrics-client'){
            sh '''
                ....
                docker build -t "${REGISTRY_AT}"/metrics-client:"${VERSION}" .
            '''
 }
```

**Question:** Why does Groovy engine interpolate the variables if they are inside a triple quoted string which will be passed to the shell step (sh -c " ") as an argument?

Maybe I'm looking at it the wrong way but from the groovy documentation, every string that is defined with single quotes/triple quotes shouldn't support interpolation/substitution

I've searched a lot of answers and documentation but cannot understand fully how the groovy engine works in the case of Jenkinsfiles and it's been bugging me for a while since the inner workings of Jenkins + Groovy + Shell related to variable interpolation (environment, parameters, local defined variables, etc) always cause some confusion, even for those that have worked with the pipelines.

Comment: Triple-single-quoted strings are not interpolated. See https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_summary_table
In your case, the interpolation is not done by groovy but it just sends the string as it is, except for escaped characters.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, there is no string interpolation. Because you defined the variables `REGISTRY_AT` and `VERSION` as environment variables, they exist in the shell script as environment variables as well.

So there is no string interpolation at the point of the triple-single quotes, but there is string interpolation in the shell script itself.

Comment: Oh, ok i think i got it. So you're saying that groovy doesn't do anything in this case (as per documentation) since the string is defined by single quotes and passes it as it is but on the other when the shell process receives this string, it expands the variables, thus the " " are dropped in the shell expansion.

Comment: So I followed with your logic until the shell part. Basically, when you use triple-single quotes, it's like passing a file with shell code and run it via `sh myFile.sh`. The line `docker build -t "${REGISTRY_AT}"/metrics-client:"${VERSION}"` is shell string interpolation. This doesn't have anything to do with groovy. And again, the reason the string interpolation works as expected is that those variables are injected as environment variables by Jenkins. If you would've used PowerShell for example you could access those variables via `$env:REGISTRY_AT`.

Comment: My mistake for not using the ,,interpolation" term. I understood what you meant  (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html.) 

Thank you for the explanation.